# Unable to create snmpv3 session and send snmpv3 trap

Tags: perl, snmp, net-snmp, snmp-trap

**1. Not able to create SNMPv3 session**

I am using NET::SNMP perl library to send snmpv3 trap.It was working fine with snmpv1 and snmpv2 but i am unable to send snmpv3 trap. I am using Mg-soft trap ringer for receiving traps but i am unable to even create a session.

Code for snmpv3 session creation:

```
my ($session, $error) = Net::SNMP->session( 
-hostname     => 'my_host_name', 
-version     => '3',
-username     => 'user-md5',
-authprotocol => 'md5',
-authpassword => 'abcd1234'
);
```

Here the username is the security user name added in Mg-soft trap ringer. Why am i not able to create session.Or please suggest me how can i receive snmpv3 trap sent through NET::SNMP library.

**2. Not able to send SNMPv3 trap**

I am able to create session for snmpv3 with some trap receiver snmp server configuration i found somewhere. But while sending trap using NET::SNMP library  i am getting following error:

*Must be an authoritative SNMP engine to generate a SNMPv2-Trap-PDUdf*

Here is the code snippet i used:

```
my $OID_sysContact = '1.5.2.9.4.6.6.5.4';
my $result = $session->snmpv2_trap(
-varbindlist => [ $OID_sysContact, OCTET_STRING, 'Help Desk x911' ],
);
```

Please suggest me why am i getting this error.

Comment: You said you were not able to send `snmpv3` trap , but in your code it seems like you are trying to send a v2 trap to a v3 connection?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few missing fields from your snippet as far SNMPv3 is concerned.

I doubt why `Net::SNMP` does not have the security level field for v3 connections. There are three levels of security - `noAuthnoPriv` , `authNoPriv` and `authPriv`. Based on the these levels, an SNMPv3 connection request can be formed.

Firstly, in your connection request, you only have authentication related information and nothing about the privacy protocol/privacy key. Second, I suggest you to use version value as `snmpv3` instead of just `3`.

For the trap part, it seems like the sender must be an authoritative SNMP engine - not yet supported by Net::SNMP module. Quoted below from [Net::SNMP](http://search.cpan.org/~dtown/Net-SNMP-v6.0.1/lib/Net/SNMP.pm)

> **snmpv2_trap() - send a SNMP snmpV2-trap to the remote manager**
>   **NOTE:** This method can only be used when the version of the object is
>   set to SNMPv2c. SNMPv2-Trap-PDUs are supported by SNMPv3, but require
>   the sender of the message to be an authoritative SNMP engine which is
>   not currently supported by the Net::SNMP module.